# What happens to isothermal compressibility at zero temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, low-temperature-physics

In chapter 11 of his book on thermodynamics, Callen states that Nernst postulate implies the isothermal compressibility (denoted as $\kappa_T$) of any system vanishes as its temperature approaches zero, though this statement is not justified in the text.

However, two related things are demonstrated in the text: one is that the coefficient of thermal expansion vanishes
$$\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\right)_P = \left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial P}\right)_T \rightarrow 0, \quad \Rightarrow \quad \alpha = \frac{1}{v}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\right)_P \rightarrow 0$$
and the other is that
$$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_v = \left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial v}\right)_T \rightarrow 0.$$

Then, using the above equations and identities of partial derivatives, I can write $\kappa_T$ as
$$\kappa_T = -\frac{1}{v}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial P}\right)_T = \frac{1}{v}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\right)_P \bigg/\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_v \rightarrow \frac{0}{0},$$
which is an indeterminate form.

Is there a way to proceed from here to show that $\kappa_T$ also tends to zero? Or can this be done in a different way?

Comment: Is there a way you can compute the second derivatives and use [de L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)?

Comment: I do not know how to calculate the second derivatives.

Comment: @Tofi did you got how to do this? I'm having the exact problem

Comment: @Aditya No, I couldn't arrive at a solution.